# android twitter login Looper.prepair

Tags: android, twitter

I'm making a login to my android application using twitter API from dialog that contains web view component

this error come from the Logcat 
"can't create a handler inside thread that has not a Looper.prepare() " 
what is the solution of this error ?
this is the code of the OAuthRequestTokenTask.java class

```
import com.noqwerty.m.LoginActivity;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
public class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private Context context;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
            OAuthProvider provider) {
        this.context = context;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
            final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                    Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
            // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACtuTION_VIEW,
            // Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
            // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            // context.startActivity(intent);
            // Looper.prepare();
            LoginActivity.twd.setUpWebView(url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

this TwitterDialog.java class

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.http.HttpParameters;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TwitterDialog extends Dialog {

    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE = { 460, 260 };
    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT = { 280, 420 };
    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    static final int MARGIN = 4;
    static final int PADDING = 2;
    private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private LinearLayout mContent;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private boolean progressDialogRunning = false;
    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    HttpParameters params1;

    public TwitterDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        try {
            this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                    Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            this.provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants.REQUEST_URL,
                    Constants.ACCESS_URL, Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider", e);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
        new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this.getContext(), consumer, provider)
                .execute();
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      try {
//          this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
//                  Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
//          this.provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants.REQUEST_URL,
//                  Constants.ACCESS_URL, Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL);
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider", e);
//      }
//
//      Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
//      new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this.getContext(), consumer, provider).execute();
//
//    }

    private void setUpTitle() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mTitle = new TextView(getContext());
        mTitle.setText("Twitter");
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xFFbbd7e9);
        mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
        mTitle.setCompoundDrawablePadding(MARGIN + PADDING);
        mContent.addView(mTitle);
    }

    public void setUpWebView(String u) {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());

        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl(u);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);

        mContent.addView(mWebView);
    }

    private class TwitterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
          ///  mListener.onError(description);
            TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mSpinner.show();
            progressDialogRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String title = mWebView.getTitle();
            if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }
            progressDialogRunning = false;
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        progressDialogRunning = false;
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!progressDialogRunning){
            TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

the Logcat output

```
 05-02 12:47:17.517: E/com.noqwerty.m.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(1703): Error during OAUth retrieve request token
05-02 12:47:17.517: E/com.noqwerty.m.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(1703): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-02 12:47:17.517: E/com.noqwerty.m.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(1703):   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
05-02 12:47:17.517: E/com.noqwerty.m.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(1703):   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
05-02 12:47:17.517: E/com.noqwerty.m.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask(1703):   at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$PrivateHandler.<init>(WebViewClassic.java:7242)
```

Comment: please give your logcat error log

Comment: The exact same question has been asked ten minutes ago. The exception basically says it all. Looking at the documentation for the classes which it names tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: @skyblueandroid007 i have edited it and added the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that some of your methods  tries to access UI from background
>   thread and fails. Move your UI logic to onPostExecute to be processed
>   on UI thread.